# Is there a way to reference the broadcast ip of a micro segmented network from another in Python on a single router?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I thought this should be super simple, but considering that I haven't been able to find much online, it might be weirder than I thought, or I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely.

I'm looking to find a way to discover broadcast packets from a micro segmented network from the context of the hidden main network. I have devices broadcasting from 192.168.1.0 on port 9999, and I would like to use the Python socket library in order to discover these and connect to them.

At the moment, this is working fine from the context of everything being on the same subnet and using 255.255.255.255 to locate, like so:

```
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
    sock.sendto(req, ('255.255.255.255', 9999))
```

Once I make the request from a device on 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.1.0, I don't see anything. My attempt thus far has been using the broadcast address of the subnet I'm looking to discover from, like so:

```
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
    sock.sendto(req, ('192.168.1.255', 9999))
```

If anyone can redirect me to a better solution, preferably using the socket lib but at this point I'm open to anything, it would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First, you should not be using broadcast, we now use multicast instead. Next, broadcasts cannot be routed. Multicasts can be routed if you enable multicast routing, which is very different than unicast routing. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host in a network, even things like printers and routers that are not interested in the traffic, and it is a security problem. Multicast only interrupts hosts interested in the traffic.

Comment: Ok thank you for this info. I'll dig deeper in this direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: Stepping back and looking at the problem you are trying to solve, maybe the Service Location Protocol (SLP) or similar (e.g. Bonjour) fits your needs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Location_Protocol